# Highcharts: how to get the data points in the zoomed window?

Tags: highcharts

I am new to Highcharts.

I have a line chart. Here is the categories:

```
 ["9/7/14", "9/8/14", "9/9/14", "9/10/14", "9/11/14", "9/12/14", "9/13/14", "9/14/14", "9/15/14", "9/16/14", "9/17/14", "9/18/14", "9/19/14", "9/20/14", ...]
```

Here is the data series:

```
[1, 4, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 1, 0, 0, 6, 8, ... ]
```

I added zoom to my chart, very similar to this jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/348sh/3/

```
chart: {
        renderTo: 'container', 
        zoomType: 'x'
},
```

I would like to get the total of only those Y values within the zoomed-in window, not the total of the entire data series. For this, I need to capture what values are included in the x axis in the zoomed window. So I added the following based on my research:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'line',
  events: {
    setExtremes: function(event) {
          console.log(event.min);
          console.log(event.max);
      }
  }
}
```

However, the values for event.min or event.max are numbers such as  3.6552511415525117, 7.10730593607306. I have no way to know which x values are included in the zoomed window. How can I find which x values are included? Any way to get the start and end x values ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did further research. I notice that I may have answered my question already in my question. It turns out that the numbers I gave in my question are very helpful, not clueless. Math.ceil(min) and Math.floor(max) are just the beginning and ending index of the data points in the data series that are show up in the zoomed window. The another thing to note is to use afterSetExtremes event. This is the moment where chart finalizes the starting and ending points in the X axis. So the complete answer is:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'line',
  events: {
    afterSetExtremes: function(event) {
          var start = Math.ceil(event.min);
          var end = Math.floor(event.max);
      }
  }
}
```

I am new to Highcharts and love to get corrected if I am wrong.

Cheers.

Comment: I have tried this code before. If you use Math.ceil and Math.floor ,it just rounds off your values  "3.6552511415525117, 7.10730593607306". It doesn't return the values similar to the xAxis categories you have used.

Comment: Swetha, the min and max in your approach are for the actual selected area, but not the final min and max that do show up on the x axis. Is my understanding correct? I have to get the all the points that do show up in the actual window. Thanks for your follow-up!!!

Comment: Your answer is correct - when you are using categories in xAxis, then each category==index. For example, `"9/7/14"` category has index==0 (arrays in JS starts with 0!).

Comment: Pawel, thanks for your confirmation! I am new to Highcharts. Thanks for your responses on a number of questions!!

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you zoom in very far, `chart.events.selection` only shows the min/max values that you selected. This solution shows the min/max of the window after zooming. This is key to show any calculations that's related to only-visible data.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you . Try this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7kv9a25r/ .

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            selection: function (event) {
                var text,
                    label;
                if (event.xAxis) {
                    text = 'min: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(event.xAxis[0].min, 2) + ', max: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(event.xAxis[0].max, 2);
                } else {
                    text = 'Selection reset';
                }
                label = this.renderer.label(text, 100, 120)
                    .attr({
                        fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                        padding: 10,
                        r: 5,
                        zIndex: 8
                    })
                    .css({
                        color: '#FFFFFF'
                    })
                    .add();

                setTimeout(function () {
                    label.fadeOut();
                }, 1000);
            }
        },
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
```

Comment: Swetha, thanks for helping me. I posted the answer I believe correct and concise, but I am not 100% sure. Thanks, again!!!