# *Highcharts* How to get the min and max value of the zoom box

Tags: highcharts, zooming

I use the Zoom function in highcharts by setting `zoomType: 'xy'` and want to ask how can I find the min and max value on x Axis of the zoom box when I use my mouse to select the zoom position. I try to use **getExtremes()** :

```
events: {
    afterSetExtremes: function () {
        min = parseFloat(this.getExtremes().min);
        max = parseFloat(this.getExtremes().max);
    }
}
```

but it seems that the returned min and max values are the values of the whole chart screen after zooming, not the box that I select to zoom.

Comment: use  events: {
    afterSetExtremes: function(event) {
          var start = Math.ceil(event.min);
          var end = Math.floor(event.max);
      }
  }

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936630/highcharts-how-to-get-the-data-points-in-the-zoomed-window

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `chart.events.selection` event to get this information. For example:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        selection: function(event) {
            if(event.xAxis != null)
                console.log("selection: ", event.xAxis[0].min, event.xAxis[0].max);
            else
                console.log("selection: reset");
        }
    },
    zoomType: 'xy'
}
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6wu1nqf/) for a demonstration and logging of the results.

Comment: Hey Halvor I've been looking in the event object and I don't see any values for first/last, it would be handy if that data is available, do you know if it is?