# how to get array or start index and end index after zoom on highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have tried to get the start and end index of selected area or zoomed area by event

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'line',
  events: {
    afterSetExtremes: function(event) {
          var start = Math.ceil(event.min);
          var end = Math.floor(event.max);
      }
  }
}
```

but it give me results like 
start 1498138440000
end 1498154397830

[i got this idea from this questions on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936630/highcharts-how-to-get-the-data-points-in-the-zoomed-window)
secondly
[i tried this example as well, but i guess this does not relate to my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-selection-points/)

my data set is like

```
[
 {
    "Camera": "Camera_Lobby",
    "Interval Start": "7/6/2017 13:59",
    " Interval Start (Unixtime)": 1499367540,
    " In": 1,
    " Out": 1,
    "IntervalMoment": "2017-07-06T08:59:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "Camera": "Camera_Lobby",
    "Interval Start": "7/6/2017 14:05",
    " Interval Start (Unixtime)": 1499367900,
    " In": 1,
    " Out": 1,
    "IntervalMoment": "2017-07-06T09:05:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "Camera": "Camera_Lobby",
    "Interval Start": "7/6/2017 14:06",
    " Interval Start (Unixtime)": 1499367960,
    " In": 1,
    " Out": 1,
    "IntervalMoment": "2017-07-06T09:06:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "Camera": "Camera_Lobby",
    "Interval Start": "7/6/2017 14:28",
    " Interval Start (Unixtime)": 1499369280,
    " In": 1,
    " Out": 0,
    "IntervalMoment": "2017-07-06T09:28:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "Camera": "Camera_Lobby",
    "Interval Start": "7/6/2017 14:31",
    " Interval Start (Unixtime)": 1499369460,
    " In": 0,
    " Out": 1,
    "IntervalMoment": "2017-07-06T09:31:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

here is my highchart setup code

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'column',
    zoomType: 'x',
},
title: {
    text: 'People In and Out Graph'
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'Irregular time data'
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
        month: '%e. %b',
        year: '%b'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Date'
    },
    events: {
        afterSetExtremes: function(event) {
            var start = Math.ceil(event.min);
            var end = Math.floor(event.max);
            console.log('start',start);
            console.log('end',end);
        }
    }

},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Number of people at a time'
    },
    min: 0
},
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
    pointFormat: '{point.y} person'
},

plotOptions: {
    spline: {
        marker: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
},

series: [{
    name: 'People Got In',
    data: vm.InData
},
{
    name: 'People Got Out',
    data: vm.OutData
}]
});
```

I need to get the selected area start and end index so I can traverse the dataset again and collect some information on the area selected.

Comment: The min/max you are getting (1498138440000 end 1498154397830) is the javascript time - it is Unix time in milliseconds. In your sample here you do not show what property of your data is going to be the `xAxis`.

Comment: the x axis should be time interval do you think, the setup here is incorrect ? I have given the sample data I wanted to plot that data on a chart x axis should be a regular time interval and y axis should be the In and Out count in the data set with give time interval

Comment: I need to get indexes not the time

Answer (score 1):

Extremes don't necessary need to be exactly where the points are.

Refer to this **live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/0j28c2y4/

I've set the first extreme different than the data point:

```
var dates = [Date.UTC(2017, 0, 1), Date.UTC(2017, 0, 2), Date.UTC(2017, 0, 3), Date.UTC(2017, 0, 4)];

var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    min: dates[1] - 12 * 3600 * 1000, //  minus 12h
    max: dates[2]
  },

  series: [{
    data: [
      [dates[0], 1],
      [dates[1], 7],
      [dates[2], 3],
      [dates[3], 5]
    ]
  }]
});
```

Then I printed out the extremes:

```
var extremes = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes()
console.log('---');
for (prop in extremes) {
  var val = extremes[prop];

  if (val) {
    console.log(prop + ": " + Highcharts.dateFormat("%d.%m %H:%M", val));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
min: 01.01 12:00
max: 03.01 00:00
dataMin: 01.01 00:00
dataMax: 04.01 00:00
```

Only `min` and `max` values are vital in this case. As you can see the minimum is `01.01 12:00`. I used `getValidPoints` function to find only the visible points:

```
var filteredPoints = chart.series[0].getValidPoints(undefined, true);

console.log("low index: " + filteredPoints[0].index + "; high index: " + filteredPoints[filteredPoints.length - 1].index);
```

The *output* are desired points' indexes:

```
low index: 1; high index: 2
```

---

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#getValidPoints
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#getExtremes